# Summation based on conditions formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to create an excel sheet which will use an excel formula to perform a specific summation. The conditions are as follows.

- Only sum for unique names only.
- The Checking Value will be the same for all unique names, so it should only be valued once.
- The Deposit Value should only be added to the total sum if the Extract Value is Y.

Therefore

```
John = 500 + 20 + 30

Mary = 125 + 50 + 45 (20 does not get added because Extract is N)

Tom = 20 + 10
```

My current formula is

`=VLOOKUP($F2,$A:$D, 2) + SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$F2,$D:$D,"Y")`

Is there a better way or a more concise way of doing this rather than with two separate functions?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get sums and counts based on unique values can often be very tedious. Your approach is actually a very efficient way of pulling out just one value for each name and separating the SUMIFs into a separate function results in a far more elegant solution than if you tried to combine the two.

The only improvement I would suggest, unless you're absolutely 100% certain that your data set will always be sorted by name alphabetically and will always include the name you're searching for, is to change the VLOOKUP to search for an exact match instead to prevent it accidentally returning an amount for a different name:

```
=VLOOKUP($F2,$A:$D,2,0) + SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$F2,$D:$D,"Y")
```

If you have a very large data set and have issues with performance using an exact match VLOOKUP, then you can use the double vlookup formula to speed things up (note that this still requires the data to be sorted by name, but it handles the issue of the name you're searching for not existing in the data):

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($F2,$A:$D,2)=$F2,VLOOKUP($F2,$A:$D,2)) + SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$F2,$D:$D,"Y")
```